# error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"data"' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: javascript, typescript

let resultArray: Array = await Promise.all(promiseArray);

```
    resultArray.forEach((result)=>{
        console.log(result);
        let data: StockObject = result['data'];  //  <--Error is hereeee

            console.log("Date: " + data.date +
                " Close: " + data.close +
                " High: " + data.high +
                " Low: " + data.low +
                " Open: " + data.open +
                " Volume: " + data.volume 
            ); 
    });
}
catch(error){
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

}

I cANNOT GET OUT OF THIS ERROR

Comment: What is `promiseArray`? `Array` needs a type argument.

Answer (score -1):

The quick workaround is:

```
let data: StockObject = (result as any)['data'];
```

The right way would be to type the `result` object correctly, which probably means using something like:

```
let resultArray = await Promise.all<StockObject, StockObject>(promiseArray);
```

or

```
let resultArray = (await Promise.all(promiseArray)) as StockObject[];
```

Comment: This is bad because it just obscures and relocates the problem which presumably stems from the type of `promiseArray`.